# Reading PDF Literal String parsing dilemma

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, character-encoding, pdf-parsing

I have the following contents in the same PDF page, in different ObjectX:

**First**:

```
[(some text)] TJ ET Q
[(some other text)] TJ ET Q
```

Very simple and basic so far...

**The second**:

```
[( H T M L   E x a m p l e)] TJ ET Q
[( S o m e   s p e c i a l   c h a r a c t e r s :   <   ¬   ¬   ¬   &   ט   ט   ©   >   \\ s l a s h   \\ \\ d o u b l e - s l a s h   \\ \\ \\ t r i p l e - s l a s h  )] TJ ET Q
```

**NOTE:**  It is not noticeable in text above, but:

'H T M L   E x a m p l e' is actually **0H0T0M0L**0[32]**0E0x0a0m0p0l0e** where each 0 is a literal value 0 == **((char)0)** so if I ignore all the 0 values, this actually turns to be like the upper example...

Some Bytes:

```
htmlexample == [0, 72, 0, 84, 0, 77, 0, 76, 0, 32, 0, 69, 0, 120, 0, 97, 0, 109, 0, 112, 0, 108, 0, 101]
<content>  == [0, 32, 32, -84, 0, 32, 32, -84, 0, 32, 32, -84, 0, 32, 0, 38, 0, 32, 0, -24, 0, 32, 0, -24, 0, 32, 0, -87, 0, 32, 0]
```

But in the next line I need to combine every two bytes into a char because of the following:

<   ¬   ¬   ¬...> is actually <0[32][32]¬0[32][32]¬0[32][32]¬...> where the combination of [32]¬ is €

The problem I'm facing is not the conversion itself I use:
    new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-16BE")

The problem is to know when to apply it and when to keep the UTF-8.

== **UPDATE** ==

The font used for the problematic Object is:

```
#7 0# {
    'Name' : "F4"
    'BaseFont' : "AAAAAE+DejaVuSans-Bold"
    'Subtype' : "Type0"
    'ToUnicode' : #41 0# {
        'Filter' : "FlateDecode"
        'Length' : 1679.0f
    } + Stream(5771 bytes)
    'Encoding' : "Identity-H"
    'DescendantFonts' : [#42 0# {
        'FontDescriptor' : #43 0# {
            'MaxWidth' : 2016.0f
            'AvgWidth' : 573.0f
            'FontBBox' : [-1069.0f, -415.0f, 1975.0f, 1174.0f]
            'MissingWidth' : 600.0f
            'FontName' : "AAAAAE+DejaVuSans-Bold"
            'Type' : "FontDescriptor"
            'CapHeight' : 729.0f
            'StemV' : 60.0f
            'Leading' : 0.0f
            'FontFile2' : #34 0# {
                'Filter' : "FlateDecode"
                'Length1' : 83036.0f
                'Length' : 34117.0f
            } + Stream(83036 bytes)
            'Ascent' : 928.0f
            'Descent' : -236.0f
            'XHeight' : 547.0f
            'StemH' : 26.0f
            'Flags' : 32.0f
            'ItalicAngle' : 0.0f
        }
        'Subtype' : "CIDFontType2"
        'W' : [32.0f, [348.0f, 456.0f, 521.0f, 838.0f, 696.0f, 1002.0f, 872.0f, 306.0f, 457.0f, 457.0f, 523.0f, 838.0f, 380.0f, 415.0f, 380.0f, 365.0f], 48.0f, 57.0f, 696.0f, 58.0f, 59.0f, 400.0f, 60.0f, 62.0f, 838.0f, 63.0f, [580.0f, 1000.0f, 774.0f, 762.0f, 734.0f, 830.0f, 683.0f, 683.0f, 821.0f, 837.0f, 372.0f, 372.0f, 775.0f, 637.0f, 995.0f, 837.0f, 850.0f, 733.0f, 850.0f, 770.0f, 720.0f, 682.0f, 812.0f, 774.0f, 1103.0f, 771.0f, 724.0f, 725.0f, 457.0f, 365.0f, 457.0f, 838.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f, 675.0f, 716.0f, 593.0f, 716.0f, 678.0f, 435.0f, 716.0f, 712.0f, 343.0f, 343.0f, 665.0f, 343.0f, 1042.0f, 712.0f, 687.0f, 716.0f, 716.0f, 493.0f, 595.0f, 478.0f, 712.0f, 652.0f, 924.0f, 645.0f, 652.0f, 582.0f, 712.0f, 365.0f, 712.0f, 838.0f], 160.0f, [348.0f, 456.0f, 696.0f, 696.0f, 636.0f, 696.0f, 365.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f, 1000.0f, 564.0f, 646.0f, 838.0f, 415.0f, 1000.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f, 838.0f, 438.0f, 438.0f, 500.0f, 736.0f, 636.0f, 380.0f, 500.0f, 438.0f, 564.0f, 646.0f], 188.0f, 190.0f, 1035.0f, 191.0f, 191.0f, 580.0f, 192.0f, 197.0f, 774.0f, 198.0f, [1085.0f, 734.0f], 200.0f, 203.0f, 683.0f, 204.0f, 207.0f, 372.0f, 208.0f, [838.0f, 837.0f], 210.0f, 214.0f, 850.0f, 215.0f, [838.0f, 850.0f], 217.0f, 220.0f, 812.0f, 221.0f, [724.0f, 738.0f, 719.0f], 224.0f, 229.0f, 675.0f, 230.0f, [1048.0f, 593.0f], 232.0f, 235.0f, 678.0f, 236.0f, 239.0f, 343.0f, 240.0f, [687.0f, 712.0f, 687.0f, 687.0f, 687.0f, 687.0f, 687.0f], 247.0f, [838.0f, 687.0f], 249.0f, 252.0f, 712.0f, 253.0f, [652.0f, 716.0f]]
        'Type' : "Font"
        'BaseFont' : "AAAAAE+DejaVuSans-Bold"
        'CIDSystemInfo' : {
            'Supplement' : 0.0f
            'Ordering' : "Identity" + Stream(8 bytes)
            'Registry' : "Adobe" + Stream(5 bytes)
        }
        'DW' : 600.0f
        'CIDToGIDMap' : #44 0# {
            'Filter' : "FlateDecode"
            'Length' : 10200.0f
        } + Stream(131072 bytes)
    }]
    'Type' : "Font"
}
```

There is no indication to the encoding type of the font.

== **Update** ==

As for the ToUnicode object, in the case of these font it is an unnecessary it should have been Identity-H but instead it is an X == X mapping here are some examples that goes from until FFFF:

```
<0000> <00ff> <0000>
<0100> <01ff> <0100>
<0200> <02ff> <0200>
<0300> <03ff> <0300>
<0400> <04ff> <0400>
<0500> <05ff> <0500>
<0600> <06ff> <0600>
<0700> <07ff> <0700>
<0800> <08ff> <0800>
<0900> <09ff> <0900>
<0a00> <0aff> <0a00>
<0b00> <0bff> <0b00>
<0c00> <0cff> <0c00>
<0d00> <0dff> <0d00>
<0e00> <0eff> <0e00>
<0f00> <0fff> <0f00>
<1000> <10ff> <1000>
<1100> <11ff> <1100>
....
....
....
<fc00> <fcff> <fc00>
<fd00> <fdff> <fd00>
<fe00> <feff> <fe00>
<ff00> <ffff> <ff00>
```

So the mapping is not in the ToUnicode object, but still other renderers can render it well!

Any Ideas?

Comment: You have to consider the font currently used. It carries encoding information. And decoding is not as simple as you try to implement it.

Comment: I guess that is what I'm trying to ask... I've added the font Object, is there anything you can see to indicate that it is a UTF-16BE?

Comment: @TacBOsS There's NO naive solution to font encoding in PDF format: you have to read and understand the specification (PDF Reference). I think it's wiser for you to use an existing library...

Comment: *is there anything you can see to indicate that it is a UTF-16BE* - it is **not** *UTF-16BE*. The contents of the **ToUnicode** stream contain a mapping to Unicode.

Comment: @mkl I've added the ToUnicode object data, it is not in there, also I've tried to force all the literal strings in the file to be converted like this: new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-16BE") and the file renders all the F4 text correctly, but now causes the rest of the fonts to be rendered wrong

Comment: @Stefano Chizzolini Thank you for your suggestion, but I've been at it for some time now, made some nice progress, and I like it :) I'm not going to let a small 'if condition' bring me down, it is just a matter of understanding where the parameters resides... BTW cool tool your clown.

Comment: @TacB0sS I'm sorry but your approach demonstrates that you haven't seriously read the spec, otherwise you wouldn't try to weirdly hack your way through the structures. Your approach may accidentally work for your specific file, but you cannot apply your simplistic assumptions to the general domain of PDF instances.

Comment: @Stefano Chizzolini I sit with the spec open beside me constantly, I've read the entire section about fonts, string literal, and anything I could think of, and please, let me worry about my seriousness. my weirdly hacks are only here to demonstrate what solves the issue not to replace the solution, if you have nothing useful to say, then please don't!

Comment: If you shared the PDF from which you select your excerpts, it might be easier to explain.

Comment: Of course http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I use: new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-16BE")
>
> The problem is to know when to apply it and when to keep the UTF-8.

The OP assumes, probably after examining some sample PDF files, that strings in PDF content streams are encoded using either UTF-8 or UTF-16BE.

This assumption is wrong.

PDF allows some standard single-byte encodings (**MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, and **WinAnsiEncoding**) none of which is UTF-8 (due to relations between different encodings, especially ASCII, Latin1, and UTF-8, they may be confused with each other when confronted with a limited sample). Furthermore numerous predefined multi-byte encodings are also allowed, some of which are indeed UTF-16-related..

But PDF allows **completely custom encodings**, both single-byte and multi-byte, to be used, too!

E.g. this text drawing operation

```
(ABCCD) Tj
```

for a simple font with this encoding:

```
<<
 /Type /Encoding
 /Differences [ 65 /H /e /l /o ] 
>>
```

displays the word **Hello**!

And while this may look like an artificially constructed example, the procedure to create a custom encoding like this (i.e. by assigning codes from some start value upwards to glyphs in the order in which they first occur on the page or in the document) is fairly often used.

Furthermore, the OP's current solution

> If your font object has a CMap, then you treat it as a UTF-16, otherwise not.

will only work for a very few documents because

a) simple fonts (using single-byte encodings) may also supply a **ToUnicode** CMap and
b) composite fonts CMaps also need not be UTF-like but instead can use a mixed multi-byte encoding.

Thus, there is no way around an in-depth analysis of the used font information, cf. 9.5..9.9 of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) ISO 32000-1.

**PS** On some comments by the OP:

> *this: **new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-16BE")** was an example to the how the problem is solved not a solution! The solution is done while fetching the glyphs whether I treat the data as 16-bit or 8-bit*

and

> the ToUnicode map is 16-bit(The only ones I've seen) per key,

The data may be mixed data, e.g. have a look at the [Adobe CMap and CIDFont
Files Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf), here the CMap example 9 contains the section

```
4 begincodespacerange
<00> <80>
<8140> <9ffc>
<a0> <de>
<e040> <fbec>
endcodespacerange
```

which is explained to mean

> Figure 6 shows how the codespace definition in this example comprises two single-byte linear ranges of codes (`<00>` to `<80>` and `<A0>` to `<DF>`) and two double-byte rectangular ranges of codes (`<8140>` to `<9FFC>` and `<E040>` to `<FBFC>`). The first two-byte region comprises all codes bounded by first-byte values of 81 through 9F and second-byte values of 40 through FC. Thus, the input code `<86A9>` is within the region because both bytes are within bounds. That code is valid. The input code `<8210>` is not within the region, even though its first byte is between 81 and 9F, because its second byte is not within bounds. That code is invalid. The second two-byte region is similarly bounded.

[image: Figure 6 Codespace ranges for the 83pv-RKSJ-H charset encoding]

Comment: I think that my terminology is wrong, thus my answer does not satisfy, but so far the solution I've applied works for all pdfs I've tried... could you please provide a link to some pdf containing a complicated font set?

Comment: and again, this: **new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-16BE")** was an example to the how the problem is solved not a solution! The solution is done while fetching the glyphs whether I treat the data as 16-bit or 8-bit.

Comment: I'm currently accessing stackoverflow merely vis smart phone, without a proper set of examples. Monday in office I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So as this seems to be complicated, and the reason for this bug is stupid, especially on my end, but there is a lesson to be learned with regards to when to treat the chars as **UTF-16**, and when not to.

My problem was not while parsing the fonts, but while rendering them. according to the details specified in the Font object you can determine the type of the font and apply the correct logic to it.

Comment: *For simple fonts, each byte of a string to be shown selects one glyph, whereas for composite fonts, a sequence of one or more bytes are decoded to select a glyph from the descendant CIDFont.* (from the PDF specification). So if you have a Type0 font, you only know that character encoding can be more complex, but not necessarily UTF-16.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the ToUnicode map is 16-bit(The only ones I've seen) per key, but the literal string might not be?

Comment: I have added a pointer to a sample CMap with mixed one-byte and two-byte regions to my answer. This CMap actually even corresponds to a named charset encoding: **83pv-RKSJ-H**.